# Hide specified Control Panel items in C#

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I want to Hide a specific item from control panel in C#, I can do it with "gpedit" with following actions:

```
Administrative Templates->User Configuration->Control Panel->Hide specified Control Panel items
```

Adding "Matrox PowerDesk" this object will be removed from control panel.

But I need to do this job with C#, I know there is a way to do it with registery in the following path:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
```

But I don't know what Key/value should I add to this path to remove this Item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is link to demostrate how to hide control panel items using Registry.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28919/remove-or-hide-unwanted-items-from-the-control-panel-in-windows-7/

If you know how to play with registry using C# then you can do this easily.